# perl - parse error using composed script

Tags: perl, parsing, html-parsing

when i use this script , its working fine
i use HTML::TreeBuilder to parse html from a site

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use LWP::Simple;
use HTML::TreeBuilder;

use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';
my $base='https://myanimelist.net';
my $url="/anime/35849/Darling_in_the_FranXX";
my $page = get($base.$url) or die $!;
my $p = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content( $page );

my @trips= $p->look_down(_tag=>'span',itemprop=>'description')->as_text;
foreach my $trip (@trips){
   print $trip;
}
```

but when i add it to this script it doesn't work

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use LWP::Simple;
use HTML::TreeBuilder;
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();


my $mal = "https://myanimelist.net/search/all?q=darling";
my $response = $ua->request(HTTP::Request->new(GET => $mal));
my $rrs = $response->content;
while ($rrs =~ m/href=\"https:\/\/myanimelist.net\/anime\/(.*?)\" class=\"hoverinfo_trigger fw-b fl-l\"/g){
my $link = $1;
if ( $link !~ /video|season?_location=mal_h_m/ ) {
print ("https://myanimelist.net/$link\n");

use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';
my $base='https://myanimelist.net';
$fullink = "$link";
my $page = get($base.$fullink) or die $!;
my $p = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content( $page );

my @trips= $p->look_down(_tag=>'span',itemprop=>'description')->as_text;
foreach my $trip (@trips){
   print $trip;
}
}
}
```

and i get this error code :

```
Invalid argument at name.pl line 19.
```

is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Well done on taking our advice and switching to a parser! :) Now if you want to learn Perl (as opposed to just solving this problem and moving on), I invite you to post you _final program_ to [codereview.se] when it works and tag it with [_perl_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/perl/info) and [_beginner_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/beginner/info). We'll give you some advice on how to improve it.

Comment: ok but it steel need more work

Answer (score 3):

There problem is here. Looks like you are missing anime:

```
my $page = get($base.$fullink) or die $!;
```

Try to replace it with:

```
my $url = $base.'/anime/'.$fullink;
my $page = get($url) or die $!;
```

Or replace:

```
my $base='https://myanimelist.net';
```

with

```
my $base='https://myanimelist.net/anime/';
```